# Checkbox CSS rule doesn't apply in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-9

My code for changing background of checkbox:

```
.question11 input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background: url(images/bg.gif) top left no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is it's not working with Internet Explorer 9.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS selector is too complex for IE. The easy solution is to give a class or id to the checkbox and the label if you can change the HTML.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="foo"><label class="foo">...</label>

.question11 .foo {
  ...
}
```

Comment: <input type="radio" value="We are currently doing it" name="q6[]" id="q6_3"><label style="float: left; width:auto;margin:0 134px 0 0; height: 25px; padding:0;" for="q6_3" onclick="uncheck('q6_',4,10);">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;We are currently doing it</label><br>

Comment: Where are the class declarations?

Answer (score 2):

Juhana is right.

The other problem is, you can't style checkboxes 100% individual via CSS only.
There are great plugins for it, so you can completely replace the checkboxes etc. via images.

--> [Uniform - sexy forms with jQuery](http://uniformjs.com/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The rule does not set any properties on any checkbox. It only applies to `label` elements in a specific context, and that’s how it works, on IE 9 and other browsers.

If you would like a rule to apply to any checkbox element that is immediately followed by a `label` element (as I guess), then you would need a different kind of selector—something that does not seem to exist in the CSS Selectors Level 4 draft, still less as supported. So you would need to add some markup, like class attributes for checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
.chh {

background-image: url(images/checkbox_bg.gif);}

 if(document.getElementById(id+ii).checked==true){
   document.getElementById(id+ii).className==chh;
                    }
```

First write css then apply javascript function